# AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer converts capture device coordinates incorrectly

Tags: ios, uikit, avfoundation

I'm working on implementing a camera barcode scanner with Vision framework. My setup seems fairly simple: a preview layer for video from the device's rear camera, frames from the video stream are processed using `VNDetectBarcodesRequest`, and if a barcode is detected, I would like to show a rectangle around it in the preview.

Vision framework coordinates are normalized to the video frame size, so I have to convert them back to the layer coordinates to be able to draw the rectangle. The recommended way to do this is to use `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint:)`. There is also a difference between the point of origin (it's in the lower left corner for Vision framework), so I have to take care of that as well. Here's what the result looks like:

```swift
let convertPoint = { (point: CGPoint) in
    let coordinateFlip = CGAffineTransform.identity
        .translatedBy(x: 0, y: 1)
        .scaledBy(x: 1, y: -1)

    return videoLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: point.applying(coordinateFlip))
}
```

The problem is that this conversion is incorrect: the rectangle ends up being rotated 90º clockwise:

[image]

I have no idea why, I set video orientation to `.portrait` on both `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.connection` and `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput.connection(with: .video)`. The Vision coordinates seem to be correct, if I convert them manually like so:

```swift
extension VNBarcodeObservation {

    func verticesConvertedToCoordinatesOf(_ targetLayer: CALayer) -> [CGPoint] {
        let layerSize = targetLayer.bounds.size

        return [topLeft, topRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft]
            .map { CGPoint(x: $0.x * layerSize.width, y: $0.y * layerSize.height) }
    }
}
```

the result is correct:

[image]

**Why is `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint:)` returning incorrect results?**

It seems like somehow `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` is stuck in the `.landscapeRight` orientation.

---

Here's how I set up video capture:

```swift
let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video)

let session = AVCaptureSession()
session.beginConfiguration()
session.setCamera(camera, preferredPresets: [.hd1280x720])

let request = VNDetectBarcodesRequest(symbologies: VNDetectBarcodesRequest.supportedSymbologies)
request.regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0.15, y: 0.45, width: 0.7, height: 0.4)

let delegate = CaptureVideoDataOutputDelegate()
delegate.vnRequests = [request]

let deviceOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
deviceOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(delegate, queue: captureSessionQueue)
deviceOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

session.addOutput(deviceOutput)
deviceOutput.connection(with: .video)?.videoOrientation = .portrait

session.commitConfiguration()

captureSessionQueue.async {
    session.startRunning()
}
```

and `CaptureVideoDataOutputDelegate`:

```
public class CaptureVideoDataOutputDelegate: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    public var vnRequests: [VNRequest]?

    private let vnHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
    private var frameCounter: Int64 = 0

    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        defer { frameCounter += 1 }

        guard
            // Try to reduce CPU usage and energy consumption by processing only every 10th frame
            frameCounter.isMultiple(of: 10),
            let vnRequests = vnRequests,
            let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        else { return }

        do {
            let size = CGSize(width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))
            print(">>> will scan a \(size) frame #\(frameCounter) for barcodes (connection: \(connection), orientation: \(connection.videoOrientation))")
            try vnHandler.perform(vnRequests, on: pixelBuffer, orientation: .up)
        } catch {
            print(">>> failed to scan frame #\(frameCounter) for barcodes: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified that both `deviceOutput.connection(with: .video)` and `videoLayer.connection` are not nil when I try to configure video orientation. Examining the size of buffer received by `CaptureVideoDataOutputDelegate` confirms that orientation is correct (the size is 720x1280, not 1280x720). Orientation of the connection is also `.portrait` at this point.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?